# How do I use multiple Displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

How do I set up a desktop PC to use multiple monitors?
I have both monitors powered on and have linked one monitor to the PC with a VGA cable, the other monitor is linked to the first one by HDMI cable, but the second monitor shows no signal.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is impossible. You **cannot daisy-chain from VGA to HDMI** (and also not the other way). This is only possible with *Displayport 1.2* and above monitors. Both VGA and HDMI need a separate connector for each monitor.

*Daisy-chaining* several monitors from one DisplayPort output is called [*Multi-stream*](https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/):

> “Daisy chaining” is a term that describes the ability to connect a series of devices together using a single connection between each two devices.  The new DisplayPort v1.2 daisy chainable displays have both a DisplayPort input and a DisplayPort output.  The DisplayPort output connects to the next downstream display.

So you need either one display output(VGA or DVI or HDMI or DisplayPort) for each monitor or you need one DisplayPort output and *daisy-chain* several DisplayPort 1.2+ capable monitors.